# Convert date string to year/month/day

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ajax getResponseHeader("Last-Modified") returns a date string in the following format:

```
Thu Oct 13 2016 13:05:17 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid, sommartid)
```

Is it possible with javascript to get the year, month and day so I can store them in separate variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let date = new Date('Thu Oct 13 2016 13:05:17 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid, sommartid)');

let year = date.getFullYear(); // result: 2016
let month = date.getMonth(); // 0-11 not 1-12! result: 9 while Oct is 10th
let day = date.getDate();    // result: 13
```

To work with dates I recommend http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. You have already a value with `date` fromat, so you could use:

- date.getMonth();
- date.getYear();
- ...

[Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)